# What is the most efficent way to screen capture? Screen capturing using DirectX?

Tags: directx, screenshot, gdi, direct3d, screen-capture

I've known about screen capture using Device Contexts and GDI, since windows XP. Is there a better way (i.e. DirectX?) now that the desktop is mostly Direct3D.

How can I screen capture using DirectX?

I want to know the most efficent way to user-mode screen capture. For a tech support program that needs frequent screen scrapes.

**UPDATE**: I don't want to resort to using kernel mode drivers.

Comment: This is a reasonable example on how to do that: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/screencap.aspx#And%20The%20DirectX%20way%20of%20doing%20it%20:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon vcsjones answer (above). See CodeProject http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/screencap.aspx#And%20The%20DirectX%20way%20of%20doing%20it%20

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure this will actually be faster than the algorithms you have in mind, but one way to do it would be to copy your buffer out using GetRenderTargetData.

[GetRenderTargetData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb174405%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method is using [Spazzarama's](https://github.com/spazzarama/Direct3DHook) application, which uses DirectX (based on SlimDx) and Easyhook to inject your capture dll into a running application's DirextX pipeline.